# How to vectorise the integral calculation?

Tags: matlab, integral

I have a function involving 4 inputs: `fun=@(T,x1,x2,x3)`. For each `T`, I want to compute `[integral3(fun(1,x1,x2,x3),0,1,0,x2,0,x3),integral3(fun(2,x1,x2,x3),0,2,0,x2,0,x3)...,integral3(fun(100,x1,x2,x3),0,100,0,x2,0,x3)]`

Of course, I can write a for-loop to do the question. However, I would like to vectorize it instead of using a for-loop. Is it possible to do in matlab?

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't work, because `integral3` function need the function `fun` to be of 3 arguments.

Comment: So it reduces to consider for-loop, am I right?

Comment: Im not sure it solve your problem because you still can't use `integral3` for fun of 4 parameters... Idea is to modify fun to make it of 3 parameters. Because just to vectorize your loop is possible.